# Is there a word that sound like сёк?

Tags: одним-словом, правописание, вид

I'm doing a little project comparing Russian hard and soft sounds.  A source tells me that сок means juice, which I believe is correct.  This source also tells me that  there's a word that sounds like "syok" that means, "he lashed".  I can't seem to find it in the dictionary.  Is there a word like this?  Or does it mean something else?  Do you know how it's spelled in Russian?  Thanks!

Comment: There is such a word as pointed in Yaroslav's answer - *сечь* (*сёк* is past tense), but I would never translate it as "to lash". It can be translated as *to cut* - "сечь мечом", *to chop* - "сечь дрова", *to whip/swish* - "сечь розгами".

Comment: Also, it shows the process rather than a single occasion, so *он сёк* would be translated as "he was cutting/chopping/whipping..."

Comment: The word "сечь", additionally, has а colloquial meaning - to understand something well, e.g. _"Он хорошо сечёт в математике." "He knows math well"_ [Wiktionary](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/сечь)

Comment: Dictionaries usually only contain infinitive/nominative forms. Don't expect them to do conjugation/cases for you.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, there is verb "сечь", which means "to lash".

"Cёк" is past tense and masculine-gendered form of it and, therefore, means "He lashed" (formally speaking, "he lashed" will be "он сёк" in Russian).

Answer (score 4):

Etymologically speaking, **сёк** (>**сечь**) comes from the Indo-European root *sek- *cutting*, from which English derives words such as **sock** (in the sense of hitting), **saw** (both the tool and the use of it), derived forms with -**sect(ion)** (as in surgical removal, *dissect*, etc.), **sect** (as in a cutoff group or offshoot) and yes **sex** (as in the division between the genders).

Answer (score 1):

Сёк (or sometimes сек - if the author of a text does not use ё) - is a verb which means that somebody was striking something (or somebody) with a scourge. Он сек = he was striking (with a scourge).

Comment: please, in future, try to provide answer which hasn't been already provided.

Answer (score 0):

There is also slang meaning of this word "Cёк" = quickly understood.